# Want to get the user info from database , and want to show on calendar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have php code from this I got complete dates of room that are booked by one user like 12-15.
And 17-18, for second user 20-21, I got marked these dates on calendar.

Now I want to show user info on mouse hover:

```
<?php 

    include 'dbconfig.php';


    $query_getaway = "SELECT * FROM getaway_table; ";
    $result_getaway = $db->query($query_getaway);
     $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'category'))  .'<br>'; 
     $resort = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'resorts'))  .'<br>'; 

    if( $category != 0 ){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM booking_request where room_id = '$resort' '<br>' ";
    $result = $db->query($query);
            if( $result -> num_rows > 0 ) {




                while( $row = $result-> fetch_assoc() )
                {
              $name = $row['getaway_name']." <br>";
               $start = $row['check_in_date']." <br>";
                $end = $row['check_out_date']." <br>";
                $guest_n[]= $row['guest_name'];
                $guest_number[]= $row['guest_phone'];


                $arr1 = range(strtotime($row['check_in_date']),strtotime($row['check_out_date']), "86400");


                array_walk_recursive($arr1, function(&$element) { $element = date("j-n-Y", $element); });

              foreach ($arr1  as $value)

              {
                  $arr2[]= $value;
              }
           $arrt= (array_merge($guest_n, $guest_number));
           //print_r($arrt);
           foreach($arrt as $val)
           {
               echo $arr_val[]=$val;
           }

    $arr[]= $value;

    }
    }
    else { echo "select" ;}

?>
```

Then in js part I showed unavailable dates, bot on hover I'm unable to show user complete info:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Add New Dates and Block Out Booked Days Below 
    /*var unavailableDates1 = ["20-5-2016", "21-5-2016", "22-5-2016", "23-5-2016", "5-6-2016", "7-6-2016", "8-6-2016",
                          "15-6-2016", "16-6-2016", "25-6-2016", "26-6-2016", "27-6-2016", "28-6-2016", "14-2-2016",
                          "15-7-2016", "16-7-2016", "17-7-2016", "18-7-2016", "19-7-2016","20-7-2016","21-7-2016",
                          ];   */
    var unavailableDates = <?php echo json_encode($arr2); ?>;


    document.write(unavailableDates);

    function unavailable(date) {

        dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1 ) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

        if($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {

            return [true, ""];

        }else {

this line is showing unavlaible on hover, i want from database user info            
            return [false, "","unavalible"];

                    <?php echo $val; ?>
        }
    }
    $(function() {
        $("#Datepicker1").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths:3,
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        }); 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: and what did you try to achieve the beautiful mouse hover effect? What error did you get?

Comment: i did not have much knowledge in js, i am unable to fetch the info on databse for two user's diff info, and on calendar it show diff info to diff user, when i am doing it is showing only last entry, on every date..